# Adding require keyword breaks vanilla JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have an HTML file as follows:

```
<body onload="myFunction('test');"
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the JS script is as follows:

```
function myFunction(id) {
    const div = document.getElementById(id);
    var html = "<p>test</p>";

    div.innerHTML = html;
}
```

This works and the word "test" is displayed when I load my HTML file in my browser running `http-server` from `npm`

But when I add the following line with `require` for `fs` to my JS script, the function gives me the following error in `VS Code`: `'projectCarousel' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`, and "test" ceases to get displayed when I load my HTML file in my browser:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Why is adding a line with `require` stopping my JS script from being executed when I load my HTML file in my browser?

Screenshots included below:

**Before adding require**

[image: Before adding require]

**After adding require**

[image: After adding require]

Comment: `require` is a node keyword, it won't work in the browser. VSCode is possibly now confused about where this JS is going to run?

Comment: require('fs') not going to work with HTML. It's node `fs` module import. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use require in the context of the browser, accessing the file system can only be done server side using node.js. Using express to serve your page could be an option.